# Equivalent of non equi join in DAX

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I have the following SQL query :

```
Select T1.order, T2.tax , T2.number, Sum(T1.vals)

From T1 
LEFT Join T2 ON T1.order = t2.order

AND T1.tax <= T2.tax
```

I want to create a calculated table in DAX, I tried the below syntax but I can't understand how to include the non equi join condition :

```
Table = ADDCOLUMNS(
           SUMMARIZE(T1,T2[Order]),
           "Total Orders" ,
           CALCULATE(SUM(T1[Order])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a DAX measure following :

```
Cost = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'T1'[Cost] ),
    FILTER ( 'T1', 'T1'[Step] <= MAX ( T2[Step] ) )
)
```

Or you can create a custom column in Power Query to get the data from the Order tabled based on the condition you mentioned :

```
= Table.SelectRows(Order, each ([Step] <= #"Changed Type"{0}[Step]))
```